# Memory corruption when building (questionable) example with Clang instead of GCC

Tags: c++, macos, c++11, gcc, boost

I have some C code which was rapidly "converted" to C++ code years back, which I now maintain. I've noticed some peculiar behavior when running it on different operating systems and building with different compilers, and could use some help diagnosing some issues I recently solved.

---

The code runs without issue on the following system:

- Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS x64
- GCC 4.8.4

After porting it over to the following system, things went south:

- OSX "El Capitan"
- Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)

---

The offending code revolves around the following structure:

```
struct blk_data {
    int i;
    int s;
    boost::mutex protectionMutex;
};
```

There's a block of code where a dynamic instance of this POD (plain old data, no custom methods or constructors, etc) is created via `malloc()`:

```
struct blk_data* pData = (blk_data*)malloc(16 * sizeof(struct blk_data));
if ( pData )
//...
```

Please ignore the fact I'm casting the result of `malloc()`. The compiler flags an error if I don't.

Later on in the code, I call:

```
boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> tempLock(pData->protectionMutex);
```

In the case of Linux with GCC, no issues. With OSX and Clang, the program faults, noting that the mutex address passed down eventually to `pthread_mutex_lock()` is invalid. Eventually, I was able to resolve this by:

- Using `new` instead of `malloc()`.
- Setting `${CXXFLAGS} += -std=c++11`

A second case where a similar issue would pop up was a chunk of code using `new`, but then `memset`ing the struct. It's to my understanding that this is safe provided one is using a POD `struct`.

Why does this code build and run fine on GCC/Linux, yet it builds, but does not run; on Clang/OSX? Does a `struct` no longer count as a POD `struct` if it contains RAII-style members, or have I violated part of the C++ standard the whole time (ie: undefined behavior)? Or is this a case of more stringent checks in Clang vs GCC.

Thank you.

Comment: That mutex is not initialized by its constructor, can't get more UB than that.

Comment: `blk_data` is _not_ POD if it contains a non-POD member - and I'm sure `boost::mutex` is not POD.

Comment: Is `boost::mutex` POD?

Comment: @Mine Most certainly not.

Comment: Just checked boost::mutex header, it uses a pointer internally so it's not POD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I'm not sure if `boost::mutex` is POD or not, `malloc` only allocates memory but does not initialize objects, that makes `protectionMutex` uninitialized.

While `new` assures that default ctor of `boost::mutex` is called and thus `protectionMutex` is initialized.

[Update] Check boost mutex's [header file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/boost/thread/mutex.hpp), it internally uses a pointer:

```
#if defined(BOOST_HAS_WINTHREADS)
    typedef void* cv_state;
#elif defined(BOOST_HAS_PTHREADS)
    struct cv_state
    {
        pthread_mutex_t* pmutex;
    };
#elif defined(BOOST_HAS_MPTASKS)
    struct cv_state
    {
    };
#endif
```

So `malloc` will certainly not initialize the pointer, while `new` does.

But I really don't know why GCC works...

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation of `malloc`:

> Allocates size bytes of uninitialized storage

Using the memory before initialising it is therefore undefined behaviour.

It works in GCC because of <strike>luck</strike> an implementation detail of glibc, specifically the fact that glibc's malloc defers to a call to `nmap` to allocate new memory from the system. By default, nmap will zero out the memory to prevent information leaking from one process to another.

Documentation here:
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html

OSX's malloc is different (although the documentation is not explict about whether new memory is initialised or not):
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/malloc.3.html